# Equivalent of getBytes() in Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, asp.net

I want to convert a class which is in Java to C#, most of the changes are done already but I have this part which I am not really sure about. I want to convert this line of code:

```
byte[] arrayOfByte1 = paramString.getBytes();
```

I have tried this:

```
byte[] arrayOfByte1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(paramString);
```

But it does not work as GetBytes() is expecting a double. I am not sure if just converting it to a double would solve the issue, so I wanted to ask about it here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on your encoding you do this similar to the following:

```
byte[] arrayOfByte1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (paramString);
```

For reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx

Comment: Please clarify which encoding does Java use by default on strings?

Comment: @CharlesO it seems UTF-16 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453269/encoding-of-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

```
Bytes[] byteAray = Encoding.GetBytes(paramString);
```

From [Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you should use UTF8Encoding.GetBytes() (or GetBytes method of some other encoding, if your string is not UTF8 encoded)