# What is the equivalent to Java's string.getBytes() in C#?

Tags: c#, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of getBytes() in Java to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089640/equivalent-of-getbytes-in-java-to-c-sharp)

In Java:

```
String s="abcde"; 
byte bar[] = s.getBytes();
```

In C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    bar[i] = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 1)); 
}
```

I worked Java example getBytes to convert C# code. But the above C# code does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encoding.GetBytes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Sweet!");
```