# Difference between String.length() and String.getBytes().length

Tags: java, string

I am beginner and self-learning in Java programming.
So, I want to know about difference between `String.length()` and `String.getBytes().length` in Java.

What is more suitable to check the length of the string?

Comment: What did your experiments suggest?

Comment: Have you tried using it on a unicode String?

Comment: `string.length` will give the number of characters in a string, where as `string.getBytes().length` will give number of bytes used by the string to store the value. In normal circumstances each character can take 2 bytes each to store a unicode value

Comment: @ArunPJohny: No, `string.length` will return the number of "Unicode code units" in the string. For ASCII text, it will count characters. For arbitrary Unicode text, it's... complicated. See BeeOnRope's answer for the ugly details.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### String.length()

`String.length()` is the number of 16-bit *UTF-16 code units* needed to represent the string.  That is, it is the number of `char` values that are used to represent the string and thus also equal to `toCharArray().length`.  For most characters used in western languages this is typically the same as the number of unicode characters (code points) in the string, but the number of code point will be less than the number of code units if any UTF-16 [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) are used. Such pairs are needed only to encode characters outside the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) and are [rarely used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567249/what-are-the-most-common-non-bmp-unicode-characters-in-actual-use) in most writing (emoji are a common [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18477578/149138)).

### String.getBytes().length

`String.getBytes().length` on the other hand is the number of bytes needed to represent your string in the platform's default encoding. For example, if the default encoding was UTF-16 (rare), it would be exactly 2x the value returned by `String.length()` (since each 16-bit code unit takes 2 bytes to represent).  More commonly, your platform encoding will be a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8.

This means the relationship between those two lengths are more complex.  For ASCII strings, the two calls will almost always produce the same result (outside of unusual default encodings that don't encode the ASCII subset in 1 byte). Outside of ASCII strings, `String.getBytes().length` is likely to be longer, as it counts bytes needed to represent the string, while `length()` counts 2-byte code units.

### Which is more suitable?

Usually you'll use `String.length()` in concert with other string methods that take offsets into the string.  E.g., to get the last character, you'd use `str.charAt(str.length()-1)`.  You'd only use the `getBytes().length` if for some reason you were dealing with the array-of-bytes encoding returned by `getBytes`.

Answer (score 9):

The `length()` method returns the length of the string in characters.

Characters may take more than a single byte. The expression `String.getBytes().length` returns the length of the string in bytes, using the platform's default character set.

Comment: There's no such method `getLength()` I think you mean `String.getBytes().length`.

Answer (score 2):

The `String.length()` method returns the quantity of symbols in string. While `String.getBytes().length()` returns number of bytes used to store those symbols.
Usually chars are stored in UTF-16 encoding. So it takes 2 bytes to store one char.
Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453269/encoding-of-string-in-java) out.

Answer (score 2):

In short, `String.length()` returns the number of characters in the string while `String.getBytes()`.length returns the number of bytes to represent the characters in the string with specified encoding.

In many cases, `String.length()` will have the same value as `String.getBytes().length`. But in cases like encoding UTF-8 and the character has value over 127, `String.length()` will not be the same as `String.getBytes().length`.
Here is [an example](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1427944920-String-length%28%29-vs-String-getBytes%28%29-length-in-Java) which explains how characters in string is converted to bytes when calling `String.getBytes()`. This should give you a sense of the difference between `String.length()` and `String.getBytes().length`.