# Why String receiver's size is smaller than original ByteArrayOutputStream's size when I call toString()

Tags: java, string, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm in front of a curious problem. Some code is better than long story:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
buffer.write(...); // I write byte[] data
// In debugger I can see that buffer's count = 449597
String szData = buffer.toString();
int iSizeData = buffer.size();
// But here, szData's count = 240368
// & iSizeData = 449597
```

So my question is: why *szData* doesn't contain all the buffer's data? (only one Thread run this code) because after that kind of operation, I don't want **szData.charAt(iSizeData - 1)** crashes!

EDIT: **szData.getBytes().length = 450566**. There is encoding problems I think. Better use a byte[] instead of a String finally?

Comment: Multibyte characters perhaps?

Comment: @Shark Not perhaps, definitely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270994/difference-between-string-length-and-string-getbytes-length

Comment: @JozefChocholacek oh i'm certain it's *definitely* but without the OP posting the bytes/characters, I can only guess.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek So there is a solution to get the entire String value or I should use a byte[] buffer?

Comment: @N0un perhaps you should be doing `iSizeData = buffer.size().length()` instead? that will avoid `szData.charAt(iSizeData-1)` crashes.

Comment: @N0un Depends what you want to do. In Java, `char` != `byte`, depending on the default character coding of the platform, `char` can occupy up to 4 bytes in memory. You work either with bytes (binary data), or with characters (strings), you cannot (easily) switch between them.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek This is the problem, I have byte[] and I want make some operations like (C-strncasecmp), so I convert it in String to do that. If I convert byte[] in String at the beginning and only deal with String after that (using StringBuilder to append,...), it's a good solution ?

Comment: @N0un Yes, convert the buffer content to String and work with String. Btw. `strncasecmp` seems to me the same operation as [String.compareToIgnoreCase(String str)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) in Java.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Tks ! You can post an answer explaining what was my problem if you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `char` ≠ `byte`, depending on the default character coding of the platform, `char` can occupy up to 4 bytes in memory. You work either with bytes (binary data), or with characters (strings), you cannot (easily) switch between them.

For String operations like `strncasecmp` in C, use the methods of the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, e.g. [String.compareToIgnoreCase(String str)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-). Also have a look at the [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class from the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library.