# Why is my java String shorter in length than the byte[] array it was generated from?

Tags: java, mysql, blob, unicode-string

I'm reading a blob from a MySql database using JDBC. I know the resulting byte array is good, I've sent it over HTTP as a string literal of numbers for each byte, and successfully downloaded the result (jpg). (just to prove mysql -> java servlet data is good).

Constructing a new string from this byte array using UTF-8 yields a string shorter in length than the byte array, and of values I can't decipher. If UTF-8 is AT LEAST 1 byte per character, shouldn't the resulting string be AT A MINIMUM the length of the byte array its generated from? (for this particular example, byte length is 12,079,474 and resulting string length is 11,501,845)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You are contradicting your own statement. if multiple bytes make a char, then char length will be lesser, right? Also, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270994/difference-between-string-length-and-string-getbytes-length)

Comment: A .jpg is not text, it is binary data. it makes no sense to try to interpret the bytes of a jpg image as a string.

Comment: If you need the binary data as a string, consider converting each byte to hex or similar to have a bidirectional operation

Comment: Oh, thanks! Ya'll pushed me in the right direction. I want a string of each byte interpreted as its unicode CODEPOINT, not a string of the byte array interpreted as a UTF-8 literal.

Comment: But if the bye array contains binary data, like a jpg image, there won't be any codepoints to extract in the first place.  You cannot treat binary data as if it were text, you can only treat text as text.

Answer (score 0):

In your bytes, you have data that is interpreted as continuation bytes, i.e. in UTF-8 they have special meaning and they form one Unicode character from multiple bytes.  That is why your string is shorter than the number of bytes.