# How to find size (not length ) of a string value in java?

Tags: java, string

Do we any lib or method which will tell us the size of string value in bytes , am checking for size not length .

can anyone help me on this

.getBytes().length  gives the length of the string not size , for example

```
String s = "Apple"
```

`s.getBytes().length` returns  5  , i think this length not size

Comment: there is a method .getBytes() this will return the size in bytes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16270994/438992 etc. I just searched for "java length of string in bytes".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bytes of a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385623/bytes-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: [`.getBytes("UTF-8").length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.lang.String-) (or `"UTF-16"`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called getBytes() 
string.getBytes().length will give number of bytes used by the string to store the value. In normal circumstances each character can take 2 bytes each to store a unicode value.

```
    final String string = "Hello World";

    final byte[] utf8Bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
    System.out.println(utf8Bytes.length);
```