# Which encoding is the C# equivalent to this java code? "Charles Okwuagwu".getBytes();

Tags: java, c#, string

say I have this code in Java: `"Charles Okwuagwu".getBytes();`

in c# this is simply `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu");`

My question is this: 
1)Java uses UTF16 for strings
2)the sting content is basically just ASCII

Wouldn't it be equivalent in c# to simply use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu");` ?

**EDIT**
I ran this little test in .net:

```
Console.WriteLine("Default:{0}", B2H(Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu")))
Console.WriteLine("ASCII:{0}", B2H(Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu")))
Console.WriteLine("BigEndianUnicode:{0}", B2H(Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu")))
Console.WriteLine("Unicode:{0}", B2H(Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu")))
Console.WriteLine("UTF32:{0}", B2H(Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu")))
Console.WriteLine("UTF7:{0}", B2H(Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu")))
Console.WriteLine("UTF8:{0}", B2H(Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu")))
```

Results:

```
Default:436861726C6573204F6B777561677775
ASCII:436861726C6573204F6B777561677775
BigEndianUnicode:0043006800610072006C006500730020004F006B007700750061006700770075
Unicode:43006800610072006C006500730020004F006B00770075006100670077007500
UTF32:430000006800000061000000720000006C0000006500000073000000200000004F0000006B000000770000007500000061000000670000007700000075000000
UTF7:436861726C6573204F6B777561677775
UTF8:436861726C6573204F6B777561677775
```

it would seem UTF8,UTF7,ASCII give the same bytes. but Java strings default to UTF16 ...

Comment: I believe it would be `Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu");`.

Comment: Better to specify the encoding on both sides.  In Java that is `"Charles Okwuagwu".getBytes("UTF-8");` or whatever encoding you prefer.

Comment: @rossum What does Java do by default? say i'm porting existing code from Java to c#

Comment: Clarifying a couple things: .NET also uses UTF-16 for strings. .NET's `Encoding.Unicode` would be better named `Encoding.UTF16LE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.getBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) in Java uses the default encoding of the platform.
So the C# equivalent would be:

```
Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu");
```

Comment: I accept this reasoning. This is the proper answer i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java uses UTF16, the equivalent .Net code would be:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Charles Okwuagwu")
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: would the output not essentially be the same if i use Encoding.ASCII, since the text only contains Ascii chars

Comment: You asked for the equivelant code.  The results of Unicode.GetBytes and ASCII.GetBytes are not the same.  Unicode: 67 0 104 0 97 0 ... ASCII: 67 104 97 ...

Comment: Equivalent code should give identical result, see my edit of the question to include some tests i ran. Unicode would give me different bytes

Comment: @CharlesO UTF-16 and ascii will not be equivalent. UTF-16 will use (at least) 2 bytes per character. In this specific case of all the characters being in ascii, it will use 2 bytes per character.

Comment: @ Gabe see Brett's comment above.

Comment: @CharlesO I guess it depends on if you want the platform default or the Java default (which is UTF16), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453269/encoding-of-string-in-java