# Java preference string encoding

Tags: java, encoding

what is the encoding of String that i get using

```
Preferences.userRoot().get(key, def)
```

on a windows machine? is it UCS-2? or utf-8? or just some cp125*? and what is it on linux and mac?

**EDIT:**
i looked at this question [What is the character encoding of String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453269/what-is-the-character-encoding-of-string-in-java)
I know that java stores Strings as UTF-16, but what about Preferences or cmd arguments? when reading strings from there does it use default platform encoding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the character encoding of String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453269/what-is-the-character-encoding-of-string-in-java)

Comment: I think you shouldn't care.  It's handled by the system automatically.  `String` is already decoded for you.  What issue are you having with the Preferences API?

Comment: @markspace , the problem is when i put some Cyrillic characters "by hand" and then try to get them, i get boxes, as it can not decode them correctly i guess. When i put Cyrillic characters using Preferences API they are converted to Unicode code points, so i think the problem is when i get string from preferences it tries to get it as UTF-16? am i right?

Comment: I think we'll need to see this "by hand" code.  Probably you messed up that part.

Comment: @markspace, "by hand" i mean without any code, manually, or if for instance i put it there from C# program    `Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\JavaSoft\\Prefs", "someKey", "someString", RegistryValueKind.String);`