# Get result of function by void** parameter as char[] with JNA

Tags: java, c, macos, pointers, jna

#### TL;DR: What JNA type do I use for a `void**` pointer (that is really a `char**`), and how do I access the result from it?

I'm trying to get a password from macOS Keychain in Java using [this C function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1397301-seckeychainfindgenericpassword?language=objc):

```c
OSStatus SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(CFTypeRef keychainOrArray,
        UInt32 serviceNameLength,
        const char *serviceName,
        UInt32 accountNameLength,
        const char *accountName,
        UInt32 *passwordLength,
        void * _Nullable *passwordData,
        SecKeychainItemRef  _Nullable *itemRef);
```

([Usage example.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH205-TP9))

The problem is, I'm not sure how to handle the `passwordData` parameter. I managed to call it from C (see bottom of post). But, in Java, I'm getting nondeterministic and incorrect results for the `passwordData` parameter. Here's my attempt to call it from Java:

```java
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.*;

public class JnaTest {

    public interface Security extends Library {
        int SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
                Object keychainOrArray,
                int serviceNameLength,
                String serviceName,
                int accountNameLength,
                String accountName,
                IntByReference passwordLength,
                // I've also tried char[][] and Pointer, which both give errors
                PointerByReference passwordData,
                Object itemRef);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Security sec = Native.loadLibrary("Security", Security.class);

        PointerByReference pass = new PointerByReference();
        IntByReference len = new IntByReference();
        int rc = sec.SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
                null,
                10, "SurfWriter",
                10, "MyUserAcct",
                len, pass,
                null);

        System.out.println(rc); // 0, good
        System.out.println(len.getValue()); // 11, same as in C
        // This prints Unicode characters nondeterministically; buffer overrun?
        System.out.println(new String(pass.getValue().getCharArray(0, len.getValue())));
    }

}
```

---

I was able to write this C program to do the same thing, and it works fine, so the problem is almost definitely with reading `passwordData` in JNA:

```c
#include <Security/Security.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int len;
    void* pass;
    int rc = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
            NULL,
            10, "SurfWriter",
            10, "MyUserAcct",
            &len, &pass,
            NULL);
    printf("%d %s\n", len, pass);
}
```

Comment: @partycoder I think I get what the pointers are doing, and I get the idea of a pointer to a buffer of chars, but I'm not sure how to actualize this in JNA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it works if I do this:

```
pass.getValue().getString(0);
```

It works. Perfectly. Unfortunately, this is not a complete solution, as I would like to avoid storing passwords in `String`s for security reasons. Playing around some more, I found that this works:

```
new String(pass.getValue().getByteArray(0, len.getValue()-4));
```

(The `-4` is because `len` is too large by 4 for some reason; I can't find anything on this in the docs for `Security.h`.) I realized that the "random" passwords it was printing before were only random in the second half, which leads me to a conclusion: Java [uses 16-bit `char`s internally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453307/2093695), so each of those characters I was getting was really two characters, and I was reading twice as far as necessary. Java was treating 2 ASCII characters as one UTF-16 character. (Shouldn't JNA handle this?)

Comment: I was going to answer that.... use a byte array and convert from there.  JNA doesn't know what the C side encoding is... works in UTF-8 but C data is not guaranteed to be in that format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have possibility to test it (as I am currently on Windows), but what if you try retrieve password like:

```
String password = new String(pass.getValue().getPointer(0).getCharArray(0, len.getValue()));
```

It is only an idea, for more useful answer I would need to debug the code.

Still, I am puzzled, why it returns 11 for length.

Comment: Nope. Java crashes with SIGSEGV. (I think that's three levels of indirection.)

Comment: @Brian you are right. I checked the documentation and my suggestion is pointing at void***.