# how can I convert unicode string to ASCII in java

Tags: java, android, unicode, ascii

I'm now trying to convert unicode font to ascii in android. I wrote following coding to convert unicode font to ascii but it's failed. Because result cannot display properly after being converted.

unicode font = 'ေနေကာင္းပါသလား' to something like '\u100F\u1039\u100D'

```
public static String toJAVA (String zawgyi) {
    String output = "";
    char[] charArray = zawgyi.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        char a = charArray[i];
        if ((int) a > 255) {
            output += "\\u" + Integer.toHexString((int) a) + "--";
        } else {
            output += a;
        }
    }       
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490218/utf-16-to-ascii-conversion-in-java

Comment: It seems duplicated but still encounter error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use java.text.Normalizer class to convert from unicode to ascii. here is a sample code from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097224/931982

```
String s = "口水雞 hello Ä";

String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
String regex = Pattern.quote("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");

String s2 = new String(s1.replaceAll(regex, "").getBytes("ascii"), "ascii");

System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s.length() == s2.length());
```

Comment: Sorry, got following error.12 15:41:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(25891): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
03-12 15:41:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(25891): [\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\p{IsLm}\p{IsSk}]+

Comment: now check i have added the line String regex = Pattern.quote("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+"); ... I just checked by myself

Comment: where did you add above line to?