# convert unicode string to ASCII in java which works in unix/linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, unicode

I have already tried  using Normalizer

```
String s = "口水雞 hello Ä";

String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
String regex = Pattern.quote("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");

String s2 = new String(s1.replaceAll(regex, "").getBytes("ascii"), "ascii");

System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s.length() == s2.length());
```

i want it to work in  **Unix/Linux** ,

Comment: you mean to say the regex is for utf -8

Comment: i got this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356716/how-can-i-convert-unicode-string-to-ascii-in-java

Answer (score 1):

There is an [ASCII character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix) for matching code points in the ASCII set:

```
String s = "口水雞 hello Ä";

String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
String nonAscii = "[^\\p{ASCII}]+";
String s2 = s1.replaceAll(nonAscii, "");

System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s.length() == s2.length());
```

As [Joop Eggan notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24424666/304), Java string and char types are always UTF-16. You can only have ASCII-encoded data in byte form:

```
byte[] ascii = s2.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Comment: _Short and simple._ The length comparison in general does not make sense. But it seems this is the answer. Any other problems are located elsewhere. However a conversion still might make sense, as some decoders may substitute special quotes (`“ ”`) and such by the ASCII quotes.

Answer (score 0):

***Explanation***

First in java text (String/Reader/Writer) is already Unicode. For the java source code (String literals) the editor and the javac compiler should use the same encoding. Ideally UTF-8.

The normalizer splits into base letter and combining diacritical mark(s) and regular expression removes those marks. Converting text with accents like `ä é ﬁ ﬂ ĉ œ` to `a e fi fl c oe` to ASCII.

Hence you would get - I think - `"??? hello A"`.

```
Charset ascii = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;
String s2 = new String(s1.replaceAll(regex, "").getBytes(ascii), ascii);
```

To prevent receiving the question marks (and distinguishing between a `?` in the original string), you can use a `Charset.newDecoder()`.

For ASCII you would still need some transliteration to latin script.

***Answer***

As most Linux operating systems of newer origin already use UTF-8 as operating system default, you probably can simply do:

```
System.out.println("We are using encoding: " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println(s);
```

Here `s` is converted to the operating system encoding.

Comment: yes exactly..i want to prevent ? character , i want it to print the PROJEçãO character to PROJECAO , actually i am able to convert it when i type the PROJEçãO to a string object , but when i read from file it prints with PROJE???

Comment: "The regular expression converts text like ä é ß ĉ œ to a e ss c oe, with accents, to ASCII." What do you mean by that? Normalizer does not split ligatures (ß or œ) nor many letters with diacritics (ø or ł).

Comment: @KarolS yes, bad formulation (partly corrected); intended to clarify should it not be clear. I did not find in the characer map the ff or fi ligatures; as using string length is not so good an idea.

Comment: `ﬀ` is \uFB00, and this ligature is normalized to `ff`. But still, normalizer doesn't do anything to ß. `Normalizer("ß", Normalizer.Form.WHICHEVER)` returns `"ß"`, not `"ss"`, and the regex does nothing afterwards.